# STL vector crash on Android x64

Tags: android, vector, stl, android-ndk, ndk-build

The following code will crash at **vec2(vec.size())** if I build the code for **Android x64** with **ndk-build** (**x86** worked well).

hello.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> vec;

    vec.push_back(11);
    vec.clear();

    vector<int> vec2(vec.size());

    return 0;    
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.cpp

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := x86_64

APP_STL := stlport_static
```

[image]

It is weird. The value of **vec.size()** equals to 0. If I change the code as follows:

```
vector<int> vec2(0);
```

the app will not crash. The issue seems to be caused by compiler optimization. CFLAG -O2 is used by default. If I add another CFLAG, such as -O0 after it, the app will not crash either.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, seems there is a bug in stlport_static.

I put trace before push_back, and after, and in the copy constructor of what I push_back.  It does not reach copy constructor if it crashed.  If it happened to not crash, then every thing's fine.

I tried use std::map, using size of map as key, it does not crash, no copy constructor is called.  Maybe std::map clone the item in different way.

Finally I use gnustl_static instead of stlport_static without change source code, everything works fine.